# How to return 3 numbers in a function without adding them?

Tags: c

Doing the 7. Reverse Integer leetcode, (**intput =321 expected output = 123**)

I don't know how to return my numbers from the function. I'm printing them as of right now to see if I'm solving the problem, and my stdout is fine but my output is 3.

Your input:
123

stdout:
312

Output:
3

Expected:
321

```
int reverse(int x)
{
int a,b,c;
 

   c = x % 10;
    b = (x / 10) / 10;
    a = (x / 10) % 10 ;
    printf("%d%d%d",c,b,a);

   return;
}
```

Comment: You mixed up `a` and `b`.

Comment: Why "without adding them"? Just consider the maths. If you have individual digits how do you get the original number from a purely mathematical stand point? Then turn that into code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to generalize `reverse` to handle numbers of any width, not just 3 digits.

Here's some code to do that (you might have to adjust the format for the `printf`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
reverse(int x)
{
    int y = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        y *= 10;
        y += (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }

    return y;
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *fmt = " %3.3d";

    for (int x = 0;  x <= 999;  ++x) {
        printf(fmt,x);
        printf(fmt,reverse(x));
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing a bit and handling potential negative values. You have the basic approach, but, in addition, you want to determine the sign of the input  and then operate on a positive value and restore the sign at the end of your function. You can do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int reverseint (int n)
{
    int reverse = 0,
        sign = n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    
    if (n < 0)
        n = -n;
    
    while (n) {
        reverse *= 10;
        reverse = reverse + n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    
    return sign * reverse;
}
```

A short example `main()` to demonstrate that takes the number to reverse as the first argument to the program (or uses `54321` if no argument is given) could be:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int n = (argc > 1) ? (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0) : 54321;
    
    printf ("n       : %d\nreverse : %d\n", n, reverseint(n));
}
```

(**note:** you should validate the input to the program and the `reverseint` function are valid integers is in the range of `int` -- that is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/reverseint
n       : 54321
reverse : 12345

$ ./bin/reverseint 0
n       : 0
reverse : 0

$ ./bin/reverseint -12345
n       : -12345
reverse : -54321
```

---

**Alternative Using div()**

The `div()` function also provides a nice variant that will replace both your division and modulo operations. See [man 3 div](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/div.3.html). The following is equivalent to the function above but using `div()` instead of `/` and `%`:

```
int reverseint (int n)
{
    /* initialize div_t with positive .quot */
    div_t d = { .quot = n < 0 ? -n : n };
    int reverse = 0,
        sign = n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    
    do {
        d = div (d.quot, 10);       /* call div with base 10, to update quotient */
        reverse *= 10;              /* multiply reverse by 10 */
        reverse += d.rem;           /* add remainder of division */
    } while (d.quot);
    
    return sign * reverse;
}
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

As already said you mixed up a and b.

You can't return multiple values.
What you can do is create one number, pack the numbers in an array, pass the pointers to function, place in a struct. You could write something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(int x)
{
    int a,b,c;
    int num;

    c = x % 10;
    b = (x / 10) % 10;
    a = (x / 10) / 10 ;

    num = c*100 + b*10 + a;

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    int x;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    int num = reverse(x);

    printf("%d", num);
}
```

If you want to return all the values separately you can write something like this for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(int x , int *a, int *b, int *c)
{
    *c = x % 10;
    *b = (x / 10) % 10;
    *a = (x / 10) / 10 ;
}

int main()
{
    int x,a,b,c;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    reverse(x,&a,&b,&c);

    printf("%d%d%d",c,b,a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you don't want to "return" a single number without the addition operation and display the reversed digits as a whole number there is a way of solving this via the usage of pointers. The code goes like this;

```
#include <stdio.h>


int* reverse(int);


int main() {
    
    int inputnum;
    int *p;

    printf("Enter input number: ");
    scanf("%d", &inputnum);
    
    p=reverse(inputnum);
    
    
    printf("\n Output number: ");
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        printf("%d", *p );
        p++;
    }

    return 0;
}


int* reverse(int x)
{
static int arr [3]; 

    arr[0] = x % 10;
    arr[1] = (x / 10) / 10;
    arr[2] = (x / 10) % 10 ;
    
    

   return arr;
}
```

As you can see, you don't need to use additional integer variables such as a,b,c since we will be storing the data of each operation you have done in a array and treat it as your new number as a whole in the output part. We do this since this is what you specifically asked in your question but there are so much more simpler ways on digit reversing etc. After returning the array that represents the new output number, we can ask our pointer to start from the first index of the array (which is the last digit of the input number in this case) untill the end. By increasing the pointer by 1 we display other digits of our input number as reversed. I hope this will be helpful